# Any Major Issues Changing OS X RAID Volume Name

Tags: macos, raid

When I set up my RAID 1 array to hold all my data, I called it Data RAID. The space in the name is now beginning to bite me with programs that can't handle spaces in path names. I want to change it to Data and I know I can do it by right clicking on the volume in Finder and making the change. Is it really that easy with a RAID? I'm sure I'll run into some applications failing to find their data, but I want to be sure I don't end up with some sort of complete loss. The OS, programs, and my Home directory are on Macintosh HD. Here's the Disk Utility display:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify if you are referring to problems you might have with RAID or with the applications.

Comment: The reason I want to make the change is that Rails, as in Ruby on Rails, fails to find a gem because there is a space in the path name. I anticipate I may run in to other shell base commands that will have the same problem. Other than that, everything works fine. I wanted to find out if there were any issues in making the change in general when a RAID is involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be that there are no issues with changing the volume name that is a RAID. I rebooted before I made the change since I hadn't done so in several months. After changing the name, I had to correct some broken links. Both iTunes and Time Machine updated themselves.